# Selecting which derived class to use at compile time

Tags: c++, class, type-conversion

I think this is a very simple question, but I don't know enough C++ to make it sound simple.

I have code that defines an abstract base class `ContinuousDistribution`, and derived classes such as `Cauchy` or `Normal`.
My goal is to have a default definition of a variable `A`, but allow the user to change that definition and, in particular, change the type of the variable. 
(I don't mean run-time re-definition, it's compile-time re-definition)

So in the default file I would have

**default.cpp**

```
... 
Normal A(0., 20.);  // Normal is the default
....
x = A.logpdf();
```

which compiles and runs assuming the default `Normal` distribution.

Then I want the user to create a "configuration" file in which the definition of `A` can be changed. In another file, *which will be compiled together with* `default.cpp`, we could have

**user1.cpp**

```
... 
Normal A(0., 10.);  // change the arguments of Normal
....
call some functions defined in default.cpp, which use methods of A
....
```

or another one with

**user2.cpp**

```
... 
Cauchy A(0., 10.);  // change the type of A
....
call some functions defined in default.cpp, which use methods of A
....
```

To solve this I tried using `extern Normal A` in `default.cpp` but that doesn't allow the variable to be redefined as `Cauchy`. 
I also tried with `extern ContinuousDistribution A` in `default.cpp`, which also doesn't work.
If the definition of `A` is removed from `default.cpp` then I cannot compile with `error: ‘A’ was not declared in this scope`, because I use `A.logpdf()`.

How can I solve this?

As suggested in a comment, I also tried to use a pointer like
`Normal *A=new Normal(0,20);` in `default.cpp` and reassign it with `A = new Cauchy(0,10);` in `user2.cpp`, but then `user2.cpp` doesn't compile because `A was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: I don`t understand what are you trying to do... why are you re-declaring a variable... In c++ You only can declare variables with the same name, as long they are in different scopes

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mess with global variables. Try writing your code without them.

Comment: Have you tried using pointer to base class and reassigning it? Like this: Normal *A=new Normal(0,20);  ... A = new Normal(0,10); .... A = new Cauchy(0,10);

Comment: @Victor That seems like a good option, but I get a `multiple definition of 'A'` when reassigning it

Comment: Could you, please, provide a fuller example of source files, preferably with includes. Are you including cpp files into each other?

Comment: Thank you for your time @Victor, I edited the question with some more information

Comment: Did you think about using `#ifdef` in your files?

Answer (score 0):

If you use headers (which is a good practice, so you should do that), you can go as follows:

**default.h**

```
#ifndef _default_h_
    extern Normal *A;
#define _default_h_
#endif
```

**default.cpp**

```
#include "default.h"

... 
Normal *A = new Normal(0., 20.);  // Normal is the default
....
x = A->logpdf();
...
```

**user1.cpp**

```
 #include "default.h"

 ...
 delete A; // Free up memory
 A = new Normal(0., 10.);  // change the arguments of Normal
 ...
 call some functions defined in default.cpp, which use methods of A
 ....
```

**user2.cpp**

```
 #include "default.h"

 ...
 delete A; // Free up memory
 A = new Cauchy(0., 10.);  // change the arguments of Normal
 ...
 call some functions defined in default.cpp, which use methods of A
 ....
```

Extern keyword tells compiler there will be variable of given type and name somewhere during linkage stage, and using base class pointer allows storing derivatives in itself.